# Connect cells to be subtracted from a cell using vba

Tags: excel, vba, button, cell

I am looking to connect the buttons to the cells in i3 and cell l3. So that whenever the number iin cell i3 is added or subtracted to the number in l3 is always subtracted from starting at 500 dollars. So if 40 is in cell i3 cell l3 should read for 460. If 60 is in cell i3 then cell l3 should read 440. I have added my code below. My code below right now just adds and subtracts from cell i3.

[image]

```
Sub Lower()
    Range("i3").Value = Range("i3").Value - 1
End Sub

Sub Higher()
    Range("i3").Value = Range("i3").Value + 1
End Sub
```

Comment: In developer mode, right click on a button and "assign macro" to that button. Within that "button code" you can call or reference your increment/decrement logic.

Answer (score -1):

### Setup Total Money with I3

The easiest way would be to have the formula of L3 = 500 - I3.

If you wish to do it in vba try this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Cells(3, 12) = 500 - Cells(3, 9)
End Sub
```

It uses the change [event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/Concepts/Events-WorksheetFunctions-Shapes/worksheet-object-events) of the worksheet to trigger a calculation of cell L3.

---

### Associate Sub with Command Button

For standard command buttons, in design mode, right click each button and then click `Assign Macro`. Then select the sub from the list.

For ActiveX buttons, in design mode, right click the button and click `View Code` (or just double click the command button). In the added click event sub, move the associated code to the newly created one.

Example:

```
Private Sub Lower_Click()
    Range("I3").Value = Range("I3").Value - 1
End Sub
```

**NOTE:** The sub's name will / must match the command button's (name) not caption (displayed text). By default the first command button would be `CommandButton1_Click()`.